# How does the NULL in SQL works in the below scenario?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, null

I am practicing SQL and realized that the ***NULL*** in the SQL are pretty amazing "*entities*".

Table "***xo***"
[Please see the link for table structure and contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bz1x.png)

When I run the following SQL query

```
select a from xo where a not in (select c from xo) ;
```

it returns **no rows**. When I run this query

```
select a from xo where a  in (select c from xo);
```

It works the way I predict.

Can you please explain how the above thing actually works? and it would be really helpful if you could supply some additional resources to truly understand the ***NULL***.

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eNtzjYTcP6JuCdETmawEQ1/0)

Comment: NULL is not equal to anything, not even itself. If you want to know more about this, [Wikipedia is a good place to start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `NOT IN` with subqueries!  When the subquery returns a `NULL` value, it has the behavior you see.  No rows are returned.

I strongly recommend `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE` for this reason.  So:

```
select a
from xo
where not exists (select 1 from xo xo2 where xo2.c = xo.a);
```

This will return the complement of:

```
select a
from xo
where exists (select 1 from xo xo2 where xo2.c = xo.a);
```

The technical reason this happens is because `NULL` is an *unknown* value, not a special value.  So:

```
1 in (1, 2, 3) returns TRUE
1 not in (1, 2, 3) returns FALSE
```

But:

```
1 in (1, 2, 3, NULL) returns TRUE, because 1 is explicitly in the list
1 in (2, 3, NULL) returns NULL (equivalent to FALSE) because `NULL` could be 1 or not
```

And:

```
1 not in (1, 2, 3, NULL) returns FALSE because 1 is explicitly in the list
1 not in (2, 3, NULL) returns NULL, because 1 could be in the list
```

So, when *any* value is `NULL`, `NOT IN` returns either FALSE or `NULL` -- and hence all rows are filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `NULL`s are treated *specially* in SQL. Whenever you compare something to `NULL` it returns *unknown*, which in turn fails the comparison in `NOT IN` condition.

This is one of the reasons why it is recommended to use `EXISTS()` over `NOT IN`.

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eNtzjYTcP6JuCdETmawEQ1/1)